# Printing the singly linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am a newbie to programming
Here I wrote a code for accepting and displaying the values using linked list.
However the code takes all the values but displays only the last value
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
};
class llist {
public:
    void create();
    void display();
    node* head = NULL;
};
void llist::create()
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = NULL;
    struct node* p;
    p = new struct node;
    cin >> p->value;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = p;
    }

    else {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->value = p->value;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}

void llist::display()
{
    struct node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << "VALUE:" << temp->value << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    llist l1;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        l1.create();
    cout << "Displaying list\n";
    l1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:
4
1
2
3
4
Displaying list
VALUE:4

I am wondering what went wrong...

Comment: I'd recommend to step through your code line by line with the debugger to see what's actually going on.

Comment: didn't got anything

Comment: What are you initializing `node * next` to?

Comment: ***didn't got anything*** I would reinvestigate. Make sure you look at the variables at each step. You should understand what the expected values are since you wrote the code..

Comment: @ZIAANSARI _"didn't got anything"_ What do you mean? Did you check the variable values? Were they all as you'd expect them?

Comment: if you don't know how to use a debugger. Use cout statements. one simple hint is use it inside each function to see if that function is being called.

Comment: As @Eddge said you are missing an initialization of `next`. You did initialize it in one case but not the other.

Comment: @brownKnight thanks got it, *temp doesn't points to the head. it instead points to the last value.

Comment: See below. There's no other node than head.

Comment: _struct node* temp_ did you copy old C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the last 2 lines in the else block.
You are overwriting the value and maintaining just the single mode in your list class. And that's the reason, only last value is displayed.
Replace

```
temp->value = p->value;
temp->next = NULL;
```

With

```
temp->next = p;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
else {
    temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->value = p->value;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

to this:

```
else {
    temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = p;
}
```

When inserting a new element at the end of a linked list, you find the last element inside the while loop and put it in the `temp` variable. Then you assign its `next` value to your new `p` element. The way you were doing before, you were just overriding the integer number of the last element. That is why when you printed your list you only got the last number you entered.

Also, when creating a new element `p`, be sure to initialize its `next` value to `NULL`:

```
p = new struct node;
p->next = NULL;
```